# Rewrite domain to cut its URI

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to set up the http://domain.com/wp1/ to be shown like http://domain.com/
I have tried to set up any rewrite in the past hours, but no success :(

P.S. There is a wordpress installed in the public_html/wp1, configured to work on http://domain.com/wp1/ URL. Its .htaccess is as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp1/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp1/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks in tons!

Comment: Have you followed everything here? [Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)

Comment: I believe that I managed to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-name.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-name.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /folder/$1 [L]
```

Changing the document root for the domain does the job.